# How to get part of a string in java script

Tags: javascript

I have initialized a variable as shown below

var abc = 123456789;

Now I need to get 6789 from the variable abc using java script.

Tried using substring and substr methods but got an error "abc.substring is not a function" when used abc.substring(5,4);

Can any one of you please help?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do: is `abc` always an integral number? what do you want to do if it is not? Is there a reason not to code  `abc` as a string with the digits between quotation marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `protractor` related.
Your variable has `number` type. 
So firstly you should make it string.
Also you have an error in `substring()`.
This what you need:

```
var abc = 123456789;
const substring = abc.toString().substring(5);
```